# How to handle Wordpress account for terminated employee

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, configuration

An employee was terminated and I want to know the best way to handle this individual's Wordpress/Woocommerce account. He was in the Shop Manager role and he mostly worked doing order fulfillment. I don't believe he was involved with producing CMS content like blogs, pages, or products.

Other ecommerce systems I have used in the past have had options to "disable" an account so they can no longer login, but I don't see an option like that. As far as I can tell the best options I have are to 1) delete the user account permanently or 2) set the role to "No role for this site", but I'm not sure if these are the best options.

I'm averse to installing a 3rd party plugin to add functionality. Any thoughts or best practices are welcome.

Comment: it depends what you want to achieve by taking actions, keep in mind though that WooCommerce is offtopic and not in this stacks scope, you can't ask for WooCommerce help here. Aside from changing their role from shop manager, what's the _specific_ concern? ( specifically, the non-WooCommerce concern )

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of definitive answer as to how to handle these so that the former employee looses all access. It seems that moving them from the Shop Manger role into a basic role with fewer permissions (like customer or subscriber) is about the best option. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an account for an employee that has 'moved away' (for any number of reasons) should have their access privileges immediately downgraded. I would also change their password to prevent access.

There are many instances of a former employee still having access, and doing improper things to the business computer systems.

When an employee leaves (or is 'asked' to leave), their access to anything should be severely restricted, even if they are given a two-week transition before actually leaving. This is especially true for the employee that has administrative access to anything in the company computer systems.